# Monitoring processes in detail over time - not summarized

Tags: linux, monitoring

I want to monitor the running processes of a linux machine over time.

My do-it-yourself solution would be:

Dump  `ps aux --forest` every minute to a file.

Background: If I get a message "something was wrong, yesterday around 8 o'clock" I want to see what was going on.

There are plenty of tools which summarize the load and io values, but I need more details.

I can do makeshift plumbing like the above dump of `ps`, but I guess there are better solutions.

Which tool could help me?

Comment: +0. Your question itself is a good one, but please [edit] and improve its title.

Comment: @unforgettableid the title was updated. Does it still need improvement?

Comment: It's still perhaps a rather ambiguous title.  It doesn't do such a great job of summarizing what the question is about.  That said, thank you for having fixed its capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give [atop](http://www.atoptool.nl/index.php) a try. It is licensed under GPL.

It has raw data logging capability with the `-w` (write) switch, which creates logs in `/var/log/atop/atop_YYYYMMDD`.

You can later analyze with the `-r YYYYMMDD` (read) switch. You specify the interesting interval with `-b hh:mm -e hh:mm` and you can define what information you're interested in, e.g.

- `-m`: memory
- `-d`: disk
- `-n`: network
- `-v`: process characteristics
- `-c`: command lines

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found this related article: https://lwn.net/Articles/387202/

Answer (score 2):

[Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) monitors server processes (and more) and restarts them if they die. You can set it up to send you an alert if a process fails. The details will be logged in a log file which you can see what happened on certain events. It even has a web client.

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monit]

Image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monit

In addition, danschultzer created a PHP based tool, [Monit Graph](https://github.com/danschultzer/monit-graph), to help graph monit data.

Comment: How can monit show me the processes tree which ran yesterday at 12:30? The screen shot displays summarized values only.